# Are there well-known tools for chasing down VRAM & GTT memory leaks?

Tags: debugging, memory

**Problem.** I have inherited a large C++ 3D graphics codebase (with some shader code). The program runs for about 1-5 minutes before crashing.

**Problem Data.** Using system tools, one can see a sharp rise in VRAM memory usage after the program launches, which eclipses into a crash. The same is true for GTT memory usage also (although the spike isn't quite as dramatic as with the VRAM).

**Questions.**

1. Does this (probably) mean that there is a memory leak in OpenGL shader code somewhere (as opposed to a leak in regular C++ code)?
2. Are there well-known tools for tracking down vram/gtt memory leaks (similar to the way that valgrind can be used to track down system memory usage)?

Comment: Is it even *possible* for shader languages to leak memory? My first guess would be that C++ code keeps pushing data to the GPU which it never frees.

Comment: @Philipp: Good question. But how would C++ code push data to the GPU outside of shader code?

Comment: By calling functions like [`glTexImage2d`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml), for example.

Comment: Shaders can not leak memory.

Comment: What OS are you on? there are different tools for different operating systems.

Comment: @user1118321: I'm on Arch Linux.